# KendoUi list view "press to load more" not working using MVVM style

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I have a list view that is created using MVVM style. I am trying to use the "Press to load more" function from Kendoui mobile. Here is my full code on [Jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/OTInERo/3/edit) Please help me. http://jsbin.com/OTInERo/3/edit

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the inset style.   The documentation states that grouping is not supported for 'press to load more' but in my experience I think the inset style breaks it too, certainly using MVC wrappers on the latest build it does.  I'm going to let them know.